# How to override CSS of ngbPopover in angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm using ng-bootstrap and want to add custom CSS for popover content.
I'm trying to apply in app.component.css but it is not applying in popover-body.

[image: Check this!! I want to apply CSS in this attribute]

Comment: app.component.css is for the styles of the app component. Angular uses style encapsulation to limit the rules you put there to the app component. Not sure what you're actually trying to achive since you didn't post any code, but the CSS should probably be in your global stylesheet.

Comment: I have added in global sheet too. But It was not applying.
`.popover-body{
    padding: 5px;
}`

Comment: Again, if you want help, post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. As a plunkr, for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use ViewEncapsulation.None. This mean that "the style is wrapped in a style tag and pushed to the head"

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
...  `,
  styles:[`.popover-title{background-color:black;color:white}`],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Comment: Its showing Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/compiler/src/core' error. I have tried both core and view imports

Comment: I have just added "styles" in component and All things messed and no styles working as default

Comment: This works if I say `styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],` and `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` . Thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

Try this to override the style
//component.css

```
::ng-deep .popover-body {
 background-color:black;
 color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, ViewEncapsulation.None can be added if you use a stylesUrl too. If you want that ViewEncapsutaion don't affected to the rest of the app, your styles can be like .custom .popover-title {...} and enclosed your ngPopover into < div class="custom">...< /div>

```
//component.css
.custom .popover-title
{
     background-color:black;color:white
}

//component.html
<div class="custom">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" placement="top"
        ngbPopover="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." popoverTitle="Popover on top">
  Popover on top
   </button>
</div>
```

If that's not work always can "simulated" a popover like

```
//in your component.ts add a variable
//customtooltip:boolean=false;
<div [ngbCollapse]="!customtooltip" class="custom-tooltip">
    show me something
</div>
<button (mouseover)="customtooltip=true" (mouseleave)="customtooltip=false">pass over the mouse</button>
```

Comment: ViewEncapsutaion which one should be included?? Or no use of that if I use 
`.custom .popover-title
{
     background-color:black;color:white
}`

Comment: ViewEncapsulation.None should be included in the component

Comment: which one to import - @angular/compiler or @angular/core?

Comment: so it's `@angular/core`